# Many to many with addition fields, Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

How could I map a custom many to many relationship with addition fields? In this case DateTime in Schedule.

**Problem now is it creates a new table named StaffSchedules**

```
public class Schedule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public List<Staff> Staff { get; set; }
    public int StaffId { get; set; }

    public Patient Patient { get; set; }
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
}

public class Staff
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public List<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
public DbSet<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }
public DbSet<Staff> Staff { get; set; }
```

**Desired outcome:**
[image]

Comment: You'll need to set up the junction table yourself (StaffSchedules) and run a 1:M relation to that table from both Staff and Schedules. You can configure the mappings using fluent API in your context file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class like so:

```
public class StaffSchedule
{
    public int StaffId { get; set; }
    public int ScheduleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Staff Staff { get; set; }
    public virtual Schedule Schedule { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Modify your Staff and Schedule classes:

```
public class Schedule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //Other Fields
    public ICollection<StaffSchedule> StaffSchedules { get; set; }
}

public class Staff
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //Other Fields
    public ICollection<StaffSchedule> StaffSchedules { get; set; }
}
```

And lastly, in your context file (OnModelCreating method):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Staff>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<Schedule>().HasKey(x => x.Id);

modelBuilder.Entity<StaffSchedule>().HasKey(x =>
    new
    {
        x.StaffId,
        x.ScheduleId
    });

modelBuilder.Entity<StaffSchedule>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Staff)
    .WithMany(x => x.StaffSchedules)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.StaffId);

modelBuilder.Entity<StaffSchedule>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Schedule)
    .WithMany(x => x.StaffSchedules)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ScheduleId);
```

**UPDATE:**

Looks like you actually wanted this:

```
public class Patient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Staff
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Schedule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public int StaffId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PatientId")]
    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StaffId")]
    public virtual Staff Staff { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This creates Staff,  StaffSchedule and Schedules. What am I doing wrong now?

Comment: Posted a picture of what i mean, don't know if i'm thinking wrong now but

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Did this work for you? If so, mark it as the answer, thanks.